# Netbeans and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, netbeans-7

I installed Netbeans 7.1.2 for the first time and it looks like it ships with Hibernate jars - When I inspect the hibernate3.jar I see it is v3.2.5. Looking here, it looks like this is a version from 2007: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/

Why would Netbeans ship with this old version? Isn't it seriously deprecated? Should I plan to upgrade? Thanks.

Comment: I always wonder why IDEs come with external libraries and frameworks bundled. Yes, this version is obsolete, and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real answer I guess - it just does!